# Android: multiple fragments within a constraint layout

Tags: java, android, fragment, constraints

In advance, thank you for taking a few moments to read through this question and point out what is most likely an obvious mistake in my code. I've done some research and can't find a similar question- so here it is.

I am trying to create an android screen that shows 3 fragments separated on the screen like this- (first fragment in upper left as a search fragment, second (beneath it as a recycler layout) and the third detail fragment which inflates once an object is clicked on from the recycler list.

Page layout example:

[image: page layout example]

I've accomplished this using a linear layout with two fragment containers with layout_weights, so when the search button is clicked in the first fragment, the recycler list takes the spot of the search fragment, and once clicked on inflates the detail container on the right, but again ideally id like all three fragments to be on the screen at the same time.

Here's the XML test layout that'd like to use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragmentTest1"
    android:name="com.swimlabs.pcms.progressionapp.SearchFragment"
    android:layout_width="319dp"
    android:layout_height="179dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/divider"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/divider2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/divider"
    android:layout_width="325dp"
    android:layout_height="14dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/divider2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/divider2"
    android:layout_width="14dp"
    android:layout_height="711dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="938dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/fragmentTest1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragmentTest2"
    android:name="com.swimlabs.pcms.progressionapp.SwimmerListFragment"
    android:layout_width="270dp"
    android:layout_height="424dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/divider2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment5"
    android:name="com.swimlabs.pcms.progressionapp.ProgressionFragment"
    android:layout_width="923dp"
    android:layout_height="640dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="9dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/divider2" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here are code excerpts how I am dynamically creating the fragments. Here is my singleton fragment class. What's commented out here is my old code which worked for with the linear layout with 2 containers.

```
public abstract class SingleFragmentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

protected abstract Fragment createFragment();

@LayoutRes
protected int getLayoutResId() {
//        return R.layout.master_coach;
    return R.layout.test;

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(getLayoutResId());

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
//        Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
    Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentTest1);

    if (fragment == null) {
        fragment = createFragment();
        fm.beginTransaction()
//                   .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                .add(R.id.fragmentTest1, fragment)
                .commit();
    }

  }

}
```

Here is the onClick method from within the search fragment. I've tried overriding the onCreateView method from the SwimmerListActivity, and also tried playing with the fragment manager, but none of this works.

```
mSearchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener () {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

//                Fragment fragment = SwimmerListFragment.newInstance();
//                FragmentManager fm = 
//    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
//                fm.beginTransaction()
//                        .add(R.id.fragmentTest2, fragment)
//                        .commit();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), 
SwimmerListActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

I keep getting an error like this:

> 08-13 19:04:59.291 21931-21931/com.swimlabs.pcms.progressionapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.swimlabs.pcms.progressionapp, PID: 21931
>       **java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.swimlabs.pcms.progressionapp/com.swimlabs.pcms.progressionapp.CoachActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #41: Binary XML file line #41: Error inflating class fragment**
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)

Where line 41 is the test.xml line where the second fragment begins.

If you can't tell I'm very new to this but I appreciate any resources or even general advice from you guys that can point me in the right direction to fix this. I don't expect anyone here to write my code for me. Thanks, please let me know if I can include any other information.

Comment: Try by removing View tag from layout or having less margin or layout_height because those seems very much 711dp or 938 dp.

Comment: Okay, you've used them other places too. just try with lesser dps like 200-300dp instead of 7 hundreds or 9 hundreds.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to replace one fragment to another use `.replace` instead `.add`...ignore if that is not the case, sorry cant post an comment

Answer (score -1):

It is easy these days. You can easily inflate fragments over constraint layout where ever you want to.

In .xml file, state three different constraint layout with IDs (No fragment View as stated above), constraint1,constraint2,constraint3. The design can be as you prefer.

Then use code like this for inflating fragments over these constraints:

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
Fragment fragment=new YourFragment1(); 
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.constraint1,fragment,null).commit();
```

Change your fragment name and respective constraint you want to inflate those fragment.

Comment: Don't use directions like "stated above". It is easy to link to the "share" link for any answer for a reference. Also, if you mean the AndroidManifest.xml, then spell that out.